# Loosin session id over SSL

Tags: cookies, ssl, sessionid

im trying to send a session of data over a shared SSL.

to load my session i have the following at the top of my core file:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
if ( isset( $_POST["PHPSESSID"] ) ) {
    session_id( $_POST["PHPSESSID"] );
}elseif( isset( $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] ) ) {
    session_id( $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"] );
}
session_start();
```

on the non SSL view it prints a differrent id to the one over the SSL. Whene i go back and forth the ids are not changing just 2 seperate ones for the shared SSL and the non SSL. How can I change the script to have one over both?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function **session_set_cookie_params()**  and set **$secure = false**

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: session_set_cookie_params( '2419200', '/', '.the-tack-shop.co.uk', false ); does not seem to work. The SSL is shared so the domain is secure-secure.co.uk...

Comment: You cannot share the session across different domains.